# Windows Phone shrinking text within table cells on email

Tags: html, css, windows-phone, html-email, email-templates

I'm trying to understand why Windows Phone shrinks the font size when text is within a table cell and the table isn't 100%/nested.

The screen capture below is of a rendering test email I'm developing. In this case I sent the email template to a Windows Phone 8.1 device (SDK emulator image), and the problem I'm describing is clearly evident:

[image: Windows Phone small font sizes email]

All the other tables that feature text are 100% width and the font size appears normally, but for the test results table that isn't 100% and uses table nesting, the font size has been shrunk to a very small factor. No matter I do I can't get it to be rendered at its intended size.

This only happens when using an EAS (Exchange ActiveSync) based mailbox i.e. Exchange because the rendering engine isn't the same as POP3/IMAP accounts.

Here's what I've tried that doesn't work:

- Viewport meta tag
- Adding a font tag with a size attribute
- Use of -ms-text-size-adjust:none;

I've looked at several other similar posts on Stack Overflow about the problem and all the suggestions don't seem to work here. For reference here's the code I'm developing and what produces the behavior above.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamesmacwhite/email-client-testing/master/email-rendering-test.html

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing many different table layout techniques, I've come to the conclusion that its due to tables having pixel based widths. Using percentages, the email displays correctly.

More can be found here:

https://litmus.com/community/discussions/387-font-sizes-on-outlook-mobile-with-exchange-activesync-based-mailboxes